Unramified lifting in abstract class field theory.
I'm trying to understand Neukirch approach to abstract Class Field Theory as developed in chapter IV of his book "Algebraic Number Theory". I got stuck on the following question: suppose $L/K$ is a finite extension of fields, I was wondering if it is possibile to find a finite unramified extension of fields $\widetilde{L}/\widetilde{K}$ with the following property:
(i) $\widetilde{L}\supseteq L$ and $\widetilde{K}\supseteq K$;
(ii) $\widetilde{L}=L\widetilde{K}$ and $L\cap\widetilde{K}=K$.
If this is not possible in general, when does such an extension $\widetilde{L}/\widetilde{K}$ exist? If I'm not wrong this should be  possible when $L/K$ is cyclic and  totally ramified, but I don't know if it holds true in general.

Abhyankar’s lemma (see eg the inteoduction of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.08869) says that, if $L/K$ is tamely ramified and $e(\tilde{K}/K)$ is a multiple of $e(L/K)$, then $L\tilde{K}/\tilde{K}$ is unramified… so the difficulty in this case would be to construct $\tilde{K}$ such that $\tilde{K}\cap L =K$ yet $\tilde{K}$ has a given ramification index...
